LLVM AliasAnalysis only returns MustAlias
I am trying to develop an alias analysis within a pass that finds out when store or load instructions access addresses of alloc instructions. I've tested it with several inputs, here is one example:
; Function Attrs: mustprogress noinline norecurse nounwind uwtable
define dso_local noundef i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
%retval = alloca i32, align 4
%x = alloca i32, align 4
%y = alloca ptr, align 8
%z = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 0, ptr %retval, align 4
store i32 1, ptr %x, align 4
store ptr %x, ptr %y, align 8 // <--- y points to x now
%0 = load ptr, ptr %y, align 8 // <--- load y
store i32 5, ptr %0, align 4 // <--- write to y (and therefore to x)
store i32 2, ptr %z, align 4
ret i32 0
}

As you can see, there are four allocations (return, x, y, z). y is pointer to x. There is write to y and therefore x.
I've come up with the pass below. But the alias analysis only results in MustAlias. So I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Is it not possibly to check for aliases in this way?
llvm::PreservedAnalyses MyAAnalysis::run(llvm::Module &m, llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager &am)
{
    // Get Function Analysis Manager
    auto &fam = am.getResult<llvm::FunctionAnalysisManagerModuleProxy>(m).getManager();

    // Get all allocations for every function
    for (llvm::Function &function : m)
    {
        // Get AA Manager
        auto &aam = fam.getResult<llvm::AAManager>(function);

        for (llvm::BasicBlock &basic_block : function)
        {
            for (llvm::Instruction &inst : basic_block)
            {
                // Check for allocation
                if (!llvm::isa<llvm::AllocaInst>(inst))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (llvm::AllocaInst *alloc_inst = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::AllocaInst>(&inst))
                {
                    llvm::errs() << "\n" << alloc_inst->getName() << "\n";

                    // Allocation inst was found - check for aliases in all other instructions
                    for (llvm::BasicBlock &other_basic_block : function)
                    {
                        for (llvm::Instruction &other_inst : other_basic_block)
                        {
                            if (llvm::isa<llvm::LoadInst>(&other_inst) || llvm::isa<llvm::StoreInst>(&other_inst))
                            {
                                llvm::MemoryLocation loc = llvm::MemoryLocation::get(&other_inst);
                                llvm::MemoryLocation alloca_loc = llvm::MemoryLocation::get(alloc_inst);
                                llvm::AliasResult alias_result = aam.alias(loc, alloca_loc);

                                std::string inst_str;
                                llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(inst_str);
                                other_inst.print(rso);
                                rso.flush();

                                llvm::errs() << "\t" << inst_str << ": ";

                                if (alias_result == llvm::AliasResult::NoAlias)
                                {
                                    llvm::errs() << "\t" << "NoAlias\n";
                                }
                                else if (alias_result == llvm::AliasResult::MayAlias)
                                {
                                    llvm::errs() << "\t" << "MayAlias\n";
                                }
                                else if (alias_result == llvm::AliasResult::MustAlias)
                                {
                                    llvm::errs() << "\t" << "MustAlias\n";
                                }
                                else if (alias_result == llvm::AliasResult::PartialAlias)
                                {
                                    llvm::errs() << "\t" << "PartialAlias\n";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

